# ref value is undefined in vue (modal, textarea, $refs)

Tags: vue.js, modal-dialog, undefined, textarea, ref

I am having trouble with getting ref from the  tag. I can see other ref values, a, but I cannot see b value by using console.log(this.$refs);
Did I miss something?  please let me know if you have ideas or solutions.
Thank you in advance

I am using Vuejs and here is my code as below,

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p> test</p>
     <b-modal
      ref="a"
      size="lg"      
    >
      <textarea ref="b" />
    </b-modal>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {};
  },
 mounted() {
      console.log(this.$refs.b); // undefined   
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: if `b-modal` doesn't have a default _slot_ the `textarea` will not be rendered so no reference. Just a thought.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. I realized what the problem is. Here is the reason, I used bootstrap-vue: 2.0.0-rc.15 , but I have changed the version to "bootstrap-vue": "2.21.2" I think there are some conflicts between SCSS and the new version of bootstrap-vue. After the roll back the version of bootstrap-vue, it is working.

Comment: I have found the reason why. Here is the reason -> the model tag is lazy-loaded in bootstrap. The solution is to add static="true" on the modal tag.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one

```
 this.$refs['b']
```